# Definition of equivariant cohomology

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, equivariant-cohomology

Classically equivariant cohomology is defined as in [Wikipedia.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivariant_cohomology)

I found the following definition in Steenrod's *Cohomology Operations* in the chapter "Equivariant Cohomology". Here $\rho$ is a group, $A$ a left $\rho$-module and $K$ a chain complex on which $\rho$ acts from the left.

Let $C_\rho^\ast(K;A)=Hom_\rho(K;A)$ be the complex of equivariant cochains on $K$ with values in $A$. [...] Let $H_\rho^\ast(K;A)$ be the homology (sic!) of the complex $C_\rho^\ast(K;A)$.

Is this definition equivalent to the original definition of equivariant cohomology as a cohomology ring $H_\rho^\ast(K;A)=H^\ast(E\rho\times_\rho K;A)$? How can I see it?

Comment: Up to now, this is what I found out: A very helpful book ist Bredon's "Equivariant Cohomology Theories" (lecture notes, 1967). Bredon defines the equivariant cohomology in the same way as Steenrod. So the definition by Steenrod makes sense. What is left unclear? The question: How does the definition of Steenrod and the usual one coincide?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is no, they are not the same.

The best way to see this is to consider a finite dimensional complex $K$ with an action of a finite group $\rho$. Then in your first definition of equivariant cohomology, $H^*_\rho(K;A)$ vanishes for $*>\dim K$. (This is easy to see, since there are no chains above the dimension of $K$.)

However, if $K$ has a fixed point then the Borel fibration $E\rho\times_\rho K\to B\rho$ admits a section, and it follows that $H^*(B\rho;A)$ injects into $H^*(E\rho\times_\rho K;A)$. So this latter group is often non-trivial in infinitely many degrees.

I would very much like to know the precise relationship between these two equivariant cohomology theories (especially when $A$ is a non-trivial module); I suppose they are related by some spectral sequence.

On a historical note, the definition you attribute to Steenrod is actually due to Eilenberg:

*Eilenberg, Samuel*, [**Homology of spaces with operators. I**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/1990380), Trans. Am. Math. Soc. 61, 378-417 (1947). [ZBL0034.11001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0034.11001).

Borel cohomology came around a decade later, and Bredon cohomology about a decade later still.

**Added later:** There is indeed a spectral sequence relating $H^*_\rho(K;A)$ and $H^*(E\rho\times_\rho K;A)$, and it appears in Chapter VII of Brown's book "Cohomology of Groups". Here the assumptions are that $\rho$ is an arbitrary discrete group, $A$ is a $\mathbb{Z}[\rho]$-module, and $K$ is a complex on which $\rho$ acts cellularly.

Brown gives a more algebraic description of the equivariant cohomology of $K$ with coefficients in $A$ which agrees with the Borel cohomology $H^*(E\rho\times_\rho K; A)$ (see Exercise VII.7.3, which treats homology but cohomology is similar). Consider the (ordinary, non-equivariant) cochain complex $C^*(K;A)=\operatorname{Hom}_\mathbb{Z}(C_*(K),A)$. This can be made into a cochain complex of $\mathbb{Z}[\rho]$-modules, via the *diagonal action*, whereby for a cochain $\varphi$, chain $\sigma$ and group element $g\in \rho$ we have 
$$
g\cdot\varphi(\sigma) = g\varphi(g^{-1}\sigma).
$$
Brown then defines the equivariant cohomology of $K$ to be $$
H^*_{B}(K;A):=H^*(\rho; C^*(K;A)),
$$ the group cohomology of $\rho$ with coefficients in the cochain complex $C^*(K;A)$ (the $B$ could stand for Brown or Borel, since they agree). To unravel this definition, take a projective resolution $P_\bullet\to \mathbb{Z}\to 0$ of the trivial $\mathbb{Z}[\rho]$-module, and consider the double complex $D^{*,*}$ given by 
$$
D^{p,q}=\operatorname{Hom}_\rho(P^q,C^p(K;A)).
$$
It has differentials of bidegrees $(0,1)$ and $(1,0)$ given by the differentials of $P_\bullet$ and $C^*(K;A)$, respectively. The equivariant cohomology of $K$ is then the cohomology of the total complex $\operatorname{Tot}(D^{*,*})$.

There arise two different spectral sequences converging to $H^*_B(K;A)$, coming from filtering the total complex either horizontally or vertically. One of these gives a spectral sequence whose first page has
$$
E^{p,q}_1 = H^q(\rho ; C^p(K;A))
$$ and with $d_1:E^{p,q}\to E^{p+1,q}$ induced by the differential $C^p(K;A)\to C^{p+1}(K;A)$. Now comes the clever part: when $q=0$ we have
$$
E^{p,0}_1= H^0(\rho ; C^p(K;A)) = C^p(K;A)^\rho = \operatorname{Hom}_\rho(C_p(K),A),
$$
since the $\rho$-fixed points under the diagonal action on the cochains are just the equivairiant cochains. It follows that
$$
E_2^{p,0}=H^p_\rho(K;A),
$$
the classical (Eilenberg) equivariant cohomology defined in your question. The edge homomorphism $H^p_\rho(K;A)\to H^p_B(K;A)$ of this spectral sequence can be used to relate the two types of equivariant cohomology. For instance, they are isomorphic in dimension $p$ if the $E_2^{p-j,j}$ entries are zero for $j>0$. These can be interpreted as certain sheaf cohomology groups of the orbit space $K/\rho$.

Comment: Thanks! I thought about your question, which relationship connects these two theories. I don't think that this will give the full answer, but Steenrod gives on p. 64, Lemma 3.3 the definition of $H_\rho^\ast(E\rho\otimes K;A)$ naturally iso to $H_\rho^\ast(W\otimes K;A)$ for any $\rho$-free acyclic complex. In Lemma 3.1, p.101 he gives the iso $H_\rho^\ast(W\times K;\Bbb Z_p)= H^\ast(W/\rho\times K;\Bbb Z_p)$ ($\rho\subset S_n$) without proof. Is this your question? But how is this iso given? Is there an iso for $A$ coefficients and general $\rho$? I would be pleased, if you could give a hint.

Comment: It is true that the classical (Eilenberg) equivariant cohomology of a free $\rho$-space $X$ agrees with the ordinary cohomology of the orbit space $X/\rho$. So, for example if we take any $\rho$-space $K$ and cross with a $\rho$-free acyclic complex $W$, we get $H^*_\rho(W\times K;A)=H^*(W\times_\rho K;A)$, which is the Borel cohomology of $K$.

Comment: The second lemma of Steenrod you quote (which is on p103 in my version) assumes that the action on $K$ is trivial, and then the orbit space of $W\times K$ is $(W/\rho)\times K$.

Comment: As it happens I've been thinking about this question myself over the last few days. I'll add some stuff to my answer.